# numpy create Mx2 matrix based on Mx1 matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a np.array with 800 values. Each value is either 0 or 1.

If the value is 0, I want to replace it with `mu_0`, which is a 1x2 array; else, I want to replace it with `mu_1`, which is also a 1x2 array.

I tried using `np.where(y == 0, mu_0, mu_1)`, but python would only broadcast the value of `mu` to match `y`, not the other way around. In particular, the error I get is

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (800,) (2,) (2,)
```

I tried expanding `y` into `(800, 2)`, by padding `y_pad = np.c_[y, np.zeros(800)]`, but I am unsure how to condition on the first value of each row.

If I use `np.where(y_pad[:, 0] == 0, ...)`, the array gets sliced back into `(800,)` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed expand `y` into `(800, 2)` with, for example, `np.repeat` so that 0s are 0s, 1s are 1s for each row. Then we can use `np.where`:

```
# first casting to (800, 1) with `newaxis` then repetition
y_rep = np.repeat(y[:, np.newaxis], repeats=2, axis=1)
result = np.where(y_rep == 0, mu_0, mu_1)
```

---

sample run:

```
mu_0 = np.array([ 9, 17])
mu_1 = np.array([-3, -5])

y = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1])
```

then

```
>>> result

array([[ 9, 17],
       [ 9, 17],
       [-3, -5],
       [-3, -5],
       [ 9, 17],
       [-3, -5],
       [-3, -5],
       [-3, -5]])
```

where the condition became:

```
>>> y_rep == 0

array([[ True,  True],
       [ True,  True],
       [False, False],
       [False, False],
       [ True,  True],
       [False, False],
       [False, False],
       [False, False]])
```

Comment: Thank you, but can you please explain why I can compare an array to a scalar? I believe np.where() iterates through each element in y_rep, where the individual element is a 1x2 array. So, by doing [el1, el2] == s, is it comparing el1, the mean, or it only works if (el1==el2)?

Comment: The broadcasting shape here is `(800, 2)`, which will be the output's shape. When `np.where` looks at each row of condition i.e., `y_rep == 0`, it sees 2 elements. If an element is `True`, the corresponding value of the output will be taken from `mu_0`. For example, `output[0, 0]` will be same as `mu_0[0, 0]`. Then `where` looks for the other element (which is the same since we `repeat`ed) it again fills the output i.e., `output[0, 1] = mu_0[0, 1]`. Similarly, when `False` is encountered, corresponding values are taken from `mu_1`. @Biliking

Comment: We had to manually repeat `y` for broadcasting, but `mu_*`s will be automatically repeated to be shaped `(800, 2)` by numpy itself.

Comment: In short, comparison of array with a scalar only happens for `y_rep == 0` which checks every entry of `y_rep` to see if it is 0 and forms a boolean array of the same shape accordingly. On the `np.where` side, no comparison is made really: it takes values from first guy (`mu_0`) where condition is `True` and takes values from second guy (`mu_1`) when condition is `False`. As I tried to explain in previous comment, condition checking and value-taking is element-wise. @Biliking

Answer (score 1):

You can use indexing:

```
## Dummy data
# The 1x2 array
mu_0 = np.array([[1,1]])
mu_1 = np.array([[2,2]])
# The boolean array
y    = np.array([0,1,0,1,0])


## Get the result:
res = np.vstack((mu_0,mu_1))[y,:]
```

And we obtain the following array:

```
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [1, 1]])
```

Comment: Thank you, this is indeed a very clean answer. However, can you please elaborate on how "[y, :]" works? Why it can be used as a condition? I think this is the key to understanding this answer.

Comment: Also, what should I do if y is perhaps 1 or 2, instead of 0 or 1?

Comment: you should edit your question to integrate all the possible use cases so the stackoverflow's users can provide a complete answer.

Comment: For you first question, I simply use the indexing capabilities of numpy's array so `my_array[y,:]`, [the documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html) is here to help you.